# Could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Option[Double]]

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and am trying to get to grips with Option. I am trying to
sum the double values members of the following list according to their string keys:

```
val chmembers = List(("Db",0.1574), ("C",1.003), ("Db",15.4756), ("D",0.003), ("Bb",1.4278), ("D",13.0001))
```

Summing as:

```
List((D,13.0031), (Db,15.633000000000001), (C,1.003), (Bb,1.4278))
```

My current code is

```
def getClassWeights: List[(Option[String], Option[Double])] = {

    chMembers.flatMap(p => Map(p.name -> p.weight))
      .groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)sum).toList

  }
```

However this will not compile and returns:

> 'Could not find implicit value for parameter num:
>   Numeric[Option[Double]]'. 
>   I don't understand where 'Numeric' comes from or how handle it.

I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to return `Option[_]`? What condition should create a `None` value?

Answer (score 1):

[Numeric](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) is used to perform the `sum`. It is a type class which implements some common numeric operations for `Int`, `Float`, `Double` etc.

I am not sure why you want to use `Option`, I do not think it will help you solving your problem. Your code can be simplified to:

```
val chmembers = List(("Db",0.1574), ("C",1.003), ("Db",15.4756), ("D",0.003), ("Bb",1.4278), ("D",13.0001))

def getClassWeights: List[(String, Double)] = {
  chmembers.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
val chmembers = List(("Db",0.1574), ("C",1.003), ("Db",15.4756), ("D",0.003), ("Bb",1.4278), ("D",13.0001))
chmembers.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

**output**

```
//Map(D -> 13.0031, Db -> 15.633000000000001, C -> 1.003, Bb -> 1.4278)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However it's the Option parameters that I want to be able to handle. That's where the compilation problem lies...

Comment: you can first flatten the list it will drop all the None from option and while choosing the groupBy use _._1.get to get the value from some and same for the value